# How to make diffuse render pass have transparent background?

Tags: transparency, texture-baking, render-passes

I have a 3D object that I want to render into separate diffuse, normal & AO maps for use as textures. I am using the *View Layer Properties* > *Passes* options to include these layers in the output render. However, the *Diffuse* > *Color* has black background, even if the *Render Properties* > *Film* > *Transparent* is enabled and *World Properties* > *Surface* is set to *Background* with completely transparent color. So, my question is, is there a way to force the diffuse layer background to be transparent?

Comment: Are you rendering RGBA (including alpha) to a format that supports it?

Comment: @RobinBetts Yes, RGBA 8-bit to a PNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alpha is a different channel (like a pass) and diffuse pass is just a color channel, you could use the alpha socke with a "set alpha" to add that to a different pass.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Already figured that I should use compositing nodes but didn't know there's a "set alpha" node, cool!